# AppEngine and Android (REST)

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, rest

i want my android app to communicate with google app engine, to be precise I want to be able to "use" appengine as a rest server. I want on the client side the get, set, update and delete methods, and on appengine i want to be able to handle those, and manage a database saved on google servers.

I don't think I'm asking to much, but online I cannot find a guide that explains how to do that in a clear way, some of you can help me? I know nothing about network and stuff, so be clear^^

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't clear enough - Really can't do much.

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

Comment: I followed half of that guide, really perfect man, exactly what i was looking for, i passed a weak searching stuff on google, i've no idea how i missed that, sorry and thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped . The right keywords + Google = Perfect Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below links provides even easier way to accomplish appengine implementation.

http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/